# Spark Button - why doesn't pressing the enter key fire click event?

Tags: apache-flex, button, click, enter, flex-spark

I'm a little confused as to why this isn't the default behaviour?

So, how do I detect the enter key being pressed on my button and fire the click event handler? (For example on a TextInput field there is an 'enter' event)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Ignore everything I posted before.

You can use the keyDown event on the spark button and create an event handler using KeyboardEvent.

```
        <s:Button label="Submit" keyDown="enter_pressed(event)" id="submit" click="submit_clickHandler(event)"/>

        protected function enter_pressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void { 
            if(event.charCode == Keyboard.ENTER){
                submit.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK)); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Mike - could you explain how the enter is picked up when clicking the button? Maybe I was a little unclear - the behaviour I would like is that when focus is on the button, when the user presses enter, this should trigger a button click.

Comment: Oh! I am so sorry I misread your question I believe. You want to handle the enter on the button and send a click event from there. I will have to look further into that

Comment: Possibly look into the keyDown event, and check in the handler there whether it was the enter key which was pressed

Comment: What's the "submit" referring to?

Comment: Have you tried this out Mike? I'm just wondering how the 'enter_pressed' is fired when the button is selected? How is it hooked up to the button, if you will

Comment: Yes I have tried this out, I updated the code to show how to add the keyDown attribute to your button to register the event. The keyDown event should only be triggered when the button has focus and a key is pressed (you can set a breakpoint in the event handler and see that it will register any key-press after being tabbed to)

Comment: @Mike there's still a mistake in your post, button id does not match the AS3 code

Comment: @Exort thanks for pointing that out, I had changed it earlier to show what it stood for but it made sense when I actually added the button declaration

Answer (score 2):

EDIT : rollbacked to original post, event will only be fired if button is selected anyways

The enter event is fired when users sets focus on the button and has nothing to do with the keyboard enter key. If I'm not mistaken, the default key for activating a button in Flash is spacebar. You could use enter by doing something like this :

```
myButton.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onMyButtonKeyDown);

private function onMyButtonKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    //simulate click if enter pressed
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
        myButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
}
```

Comment: Hi Exort - thanks for the reply. There is no .selected property of a Spark Button?

Comment: No problem Exort. If you could post a working code sample for your suggestion, I'll try it

Comment: Rollbacked answer and removed .selected part, some wires touched when I wrote that, event will only be fired if focus is on button anyways